# Установка MSVC без Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-10

Можно ли установить минимальное окружение для компиляции свежим компилятором MSVC (x64 msvc v19.24 или новее) из командной строки, не скачивая и/или устанавливая Visual Studio? Если да, то как?

Интересуют официальные решения, а не пользовательские архивы на файлообменниках.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

Comment: @timur это руководство, как использовать компилятор из командной строки. А меня интересует, как установить без VS

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/downloads/ -> `Инструменты для Visual Studio 2019` -> `Build Tools для Visual Studio 2019` - это?

Comment: @user7860670 это установит действительно минимальное окружение? Или будет MFC, ATL и ещё невесть что?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, отличная ссылка. Можно как-то обойтись без CLI, .NET, ATL, MFC, VS 2015 C++ build tools или только вручную удалять? Или всё что recommended и optional можно в чекбоксах убрать?

Comment: там же указана опциональность для каждого из компонентов

Comment: @user7860670 опциональность означает, что "они будут устанавливаться, но можно удалить" или "можно не устанавливать"?

Comment: там же написано - By default, the Required components will be installed when you install the workload. Соответственно все остальное надо ставить явно.

Comment: @user7860670 понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, вы можете скачать с официального сайта microsoft BuiltTools от нужной вам Visual Studio. Также эти инструменты можно подключить например к VSCode. Подробная инструкция в разрезе установки BuildTools и подключению к VSCode [здесь](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).

Upd [VSBuildTools Component Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Это установит действительно минимальное окружение? Или будет MFC, ATL и ещё невесть что?

Comment: mfc там не будет. А вот невесть что - конечно.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ вот [эту ссылку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019) ещё, там показано, что конкретно будет устанавливаться и required/recommended/optional

Comment: MFC и ATL там есть, необходимо только проставить галочки тех опций, которые вам требуются.